# multiple bquote items in legend of an R plot

Tags: r, plot, legend, plotmath

Following works, (copy & paste into R)

```
a=123
plot(1,1)
legend('bottomleft',legend=bquote(theta == .(a)))
```

I want to have multiple items in the legend.
All with greek letters.
As a simple example, if I repeat the item twice the code does not work anymore

```
a=123
plot(1,1)
legend('bottomleft',legend=c(bquote(theta == .(a)),bquote(theta == .(a))))
```

I have tried many more complicated expressions but they all did not work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In this case, plotmath is not able to coerce the list of calls to expressions.

```
> cs <- c(bquote(theta == .(a)),bquote(theta == .(a)))
> cs
[[1]]
theta == 123

[[2]]
theta == 123

> sapply(cs, class)
[1] "call" "call"
```

You can make this work if you coerce to expressions yourself:

```
> c(as.expression(bquote(theta == .(a))), as.expression(bquote(theta == .(a))))
expression(theta == 123, theta == 123)
> plot(1,1)
> legend('bottomleft',legend= c(as.expression(bquote(theta == .(a))), 
+                               as.expression(bquote(theta == .(a)))))
```

Another way is to coerce the original list of calls to expressions using `sapply`:

```
plot(1,1)
legend("bottomleft", 
       sapply(c(bquote(theta == .(a)), bquote(theta == .(a))), as.expression))
```

Comment: @Gavin: I seem to remember a long exchange on Rhelp several years ago where Thomas Lumley finally came up with an sapply(..., as.expression) solution. I've tried to locate it without success on other occasions, but now I know where to find another copy :-)

Answer (score 1):

To coerce the original list of calls to expressions it is not necessary to use `sapply()`. It suffices to use `as.expression()` only for one of the components within the `c()` construct:

```
plot(1,1)
legend("bottomleft", 
       c(as.expression(bquote(theta == .(a))), bquote(theta == .(a))))
```

`c()` will then automatically coerce the whole `list`, to the `expression` class.