# Handle ggplot2 axis text face programmatically

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression

(x-posted to [community.rstudio.com](https://community.rstudio.com/t/handle-ggplot2-axis-text-face-programmatically/6898))

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the axis text in `ggplot2` programatically or if there is some native way to do this in `ggplot2`. In this reprex, the idea is that I want to bold the axis text of a variable `y` that has an absolute value of `x` over 1.5. I can add it in manually via `theme()`, and that works fine:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

set.seed(2939)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(15), y = paste0("y", 1:15), group = rep(1:3, 5))

df <- mutate(df, big_number = abs(x) > 1.5, face = ifelse(big_number, "bold", 
  "plain"))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = fct_inorder(y), col = big_number)) + geom_point() + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face = df$face))

p
```

Plot 1 with no facets
[image: Plot 1 with no facets]

But if I facet it by `group`, `y` gets reordered and `ggplot2` has no idea how `face` is connected to `df` and thus `y`, so it just bolds in the same order as the first plot.

```
p + facet_grid(group ~ .)
```

Plot 2 with facets
[image: Plot 2 with facets]

And it's worse if I use a different scale for each.

```
p + facet_grid(group ~ ., scales = "free")
```

Plot 3 with facets and different scales
[image: Plot 3 with facets and different scales]

What do you think? Is there a general way to handle this that would work consistently here?

Comment: Related: [ggplot2: Coloring axis text on a faceted plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843759/ggplot2-coloring-axis-text-on-a-faceted-plot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea: Don't change theme, change y-axis labels. Create a call for every `y` with `if`/`else` condition and parse it with `parse`.

Not the most elegant solution (using for loop), but works (need loop as `bquote` doesn't work with `ifelse`). I always get confused when trying to work with multiple expressions (more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210346/multiple-bquote-items-in-legend-of-an-r-plot)).

Code:

```
# Create data
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(2939)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(15), y = paste0("y", 1:15), group = rep(1:3, 5)) %>%
    mutate(yF = fct_inorder(y),
           big_number = abs(x) > 1.5)

# Expressions for y-axis
# ifelse doesn't work
# ifelse(df$big_number, bquote(bold(1)), bquote(plain(2)))
yExp <- c() # Ignore terrible way of concatenating 
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if (df$big_number[i]) {
        yExp <- c(yExp, bquote(bold(.(as.character(df$yF[i])))))
    } else {
        yExp <- c(yExp, bquote(plain(.(as.character(df$yF[i])))))
    }
}

# Plot with facets
ggplot(df, aes(x, yF, col = big_number)) + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_discrete(breaks = levels(df$yF), 
                     labels = parse(text = yExp)) +
    facet_grid(group ~ ., scales = "free")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Interesting! I tried a similar approach where I used a function in labels to process it. I think using scale labels might be as close as this can get.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @PoGibas, I also used a function in `scale_y_discrete()`, which works, too.

```r
bold_labels <- function(breaks) {
  big_nums <- filter(df, y %in% breaks) %>%
    pull(big_number)
  labels <- purrr::map2(
    breaks, big_nums,
    ~ if (.y) bquote(bold(.(.x))) else bquote(plain(.(.x)))
  )
  parse(text = labels)
}

ggplot(df, aes(x, fct_inorder(y), col = big_number)) + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_discrete(labels = bold_labels) +
    facet_grid(group ~ ., scales = "free")
```